# If/Else Statement for Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm still trying to wrap my head around PHP (no pun intended) and am trying to get something to work using the [Advanced Custom Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)s plugin in WordPress.

So, I've got a repeater field that's made up of two Number Fields and a True/False field. I'm basically trying to write a statement like this:

If the True/False field is `true` then `echo` both `sub_field_1` and `sub_field_2`, else echo just `sub_field_1`.

So far, I've got this:

```
<?php       
while(has_sub_field('parent_repeater')) {

    if( the_sub_field('true') ) { 
      echo '<p>' . get_sub_field('sub_field_1') . get_sub_field('sub_field_2') . '</p>';
    }

    else  {
      echo '<p>' . get_sub_field('sub_field_1') . '</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm currently going through the ACF documentation, if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
<ul class="list">

<?php while ( have_rows('blend') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <?php
        $field = get_sub_field_object('blend');
        $value = the_sub_field('blend');
        $label = $field['choices'][ $value ];
    ?>

    <li>
        <span>Pct: <?php the_sub_field('percentage'); ?> Mix: <?php the_sub_field('mix'); ?></span>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>

<?php else :

echo '<p>No Rows found</p>';

endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if( get_field('parent_repeater') ) : while( has_sub_field('parent_repeater') ) :

    $some_bool = get_sub_field('true');
    $sf1 = get_sub_field('sub_field_1');
    $sf2 = get_sub_field('sub_field_2');

    if( $some_bool == true ){
        echo $sf1 . $sf2;
    } else {
        echo $sf1;
    }

endwhile; endif;
?>
```

You must use the non-echoing version of the function. Use the get version. Also, I advise you to use safer name for fields. These seem a little dangerous. Maybe just me.

Answer (score 0):

[`the_sub_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_sub_field/) [echo](http://www.php.net/echo)s the value, so can't be used in a conditional. Use [`get_sub_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_sub_field/) instead, which [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)s the value.

This is also the pattern for most of WordPress core, there are often `get_` and `the_` versions of functions which will return and echo values respectively.

Comment: I've edited my original question above, and tried to use `get_sub_field`instead. Still though, I can't seem to get the value's label to appear. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: same problem: `$value = the_sub_field('blend');` you can't do variable assignment with `the_`, use `get_`